# Using the internal Storage from a non activity class in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am decrypting a video before playing it in Android. When I decrypt it I want to store in the Android private folder so other apps and users cannot access it - I ve looked up some code which looks like this

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I am calling this from a helper class which is not an activity class. How do I do this ? It seems to be expecting a call from an activity. And then how do I play it eventually from the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By instancing your helpers class your constructor should accept Context as an extra argument and save it as a class member.
So in the calling activity you can just pass `this` into it.

Then call `ctx.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` - assuming you named the class member `ctx`.

Answer (score 0):

Create static reference for `ApplicationContext` somewhere when your application gets started (Extending application class and doing it is better option) and then access it to use file Storage..